# Accessing SQL Server on Apache 2.4.18 and PHP 7.0.3 in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, windows-server-2012

I was provided a `2012 R2` server with SQL Server installed.  I installed the 64 bit versions of Apache `2.4.18` and PHP `7.0.3` successfully, but it does not look like MS has DLLs for SQL Server in this configuration.  I had developed in XAMPP using MySQL but this is not an option for the final configuration and SQL Server must be used.

I've tried some other configurations with no joy.  Do I have any options other than falling back to PHP `5` and 32 bit versions?

Comment: So you want to access a sql server database from php...did you check the mssql drivers for php

Comment: I did and it appears that the only drivers available are for PHP 5.4 but I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss something.

Comment: You can check on this drivers: https://github.com/thomsonreuters/msphpsql

Comment: I was able to find drivers for 5.4, 64 bit and am running on those now.  I'll watch for the maturity of the PHP 7 drivers and thank you for the link!